# Java on iPhone/iOS via LLVM

Tags: java, xcode, llvm

So, LLVM can compile java bytecode into llvm IF, right (via the tool class2llvm)? And the LLVM IF can be translated to any kind of target machine. So, since Xcode has a llvm "stack", shouldnt it be possible quite easily to take the IF, that was produced from a java class, and link it into a nice iPhone app? Anybody any experience or an idea how that could be done?

Comment: Q: What's your question?  If you're asking "can I run Java apps on an iPhone?", Yes: there are several approaches.  Including [Cloud Browse](http://www.ehow.com/how_6771908_use-java-iphone.html).  If you're asking "can I write a Java app, then use LLVM to translate it into an iOS app?", No: probably not ;)

Comment: Isn't your second question-candidate kind of the title of this stack?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but not trivial. Getting Java code compiled to llvm bitcode is the least of the problems. Bigger problem is all the Java runtime that you'll need to support to make code run (like standard libraries, types, garbage collector, etc...).

Comment: How about the VMKit project? This is a JVM implementation on top of LLVM.